# VS 2010 Find/Replace Addon?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, replace

Is there an addon or anything that would enhance the built in find/replace in Visual Studio? I'm specifically looking for something that would allow me to skip the current file (how many times have I been searching and had to hit "Next" a million times because that word occurs a lot in the current file but I know it's not in there), only search specific file types, etc.

Not sure if this is out there or not. If not, might be a good project to take on.

Comment: Not sure if it has the feature you're looking for, but I've heard good things about [this package](http://entrian.com/source-search/), developed by [one of our own Stack Overflow users](http://stackoverflow.com/users/21886/richiehindle).